# Cannot create the source distribuion using python setup.py sdist

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I'm trying to upload my code to PyPI, but when i try to create the source distribution I get the following error:

error: package directory 'rmn' does not exist

The directory and the setup.py are below

[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNDjN.png)

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
name='rmn',
version='1.0.0',
author='Guilherme Campos, Tiago Moraes',
author_email='guilhermesouza0911@ufmg.br',
packages=['rmn']
)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is in Portugese. Please try [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I will close it and repost there

Comment: Or translate into English and leave here.

Comment: Directory `rmn/` must be a subdirectory of the root directory where `setup.py` resides. See examples at https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/examples.html#pure-python-distribution-by-package and https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/